# Why does defined input variable return nil after exception occurs?

Tags: ruby, exception

I've noticed this strange behavior with the `begin/rescue` block in Ruby, when I define a variable, and an exception occurs and I try to call that variable that the exception occurred on it returns `nil`.

For example:

```
begin
  print "Enter a number: "
  input = Integer(gets.chomp)
  sum = input + 5
  puts "This is your number plus five: #{sum}"
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "#{input}" #This outputs nil
end
```

Why does the `begin/rescue` block work like this, and is there a way to print the variable without it returning nil?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the exception occurs before the value is set, control passes to the exception handler, like it should.

Comment: As @DaveNewton pointed out. The exception occurs at `Integer(gets.chomp)`, while passing an invalid value, hence the nil value for `input`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Is there a way to get and store the value before the exception occurs?

Comment: @Practical1, there's, see Ursus answer.

Comment: Always keep your error prone operations inside your begin block. variables assignment must be out of begin block

Comment: @ray Thanks for the helpful advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want but I try

```
input = gets.chomp
begin
  number = Integer(input)
  puts "your number plus five: #{number + 5}"
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "#{input} is not a valid number"
end
```